Why should I not power a mains voltage lamp with grounded cord from a power bank?
I have a lamp with a power cord that includes a ground connection. I have a mains voltage power bank that obviously doesn't supply ground. Why should I not rig up a cable that connects the lamp to the power bank?
Reasons why this is not safe:

It's never safe not to ground an appliance that should be grounded based on its power cord.
The resulting cable could be used for other stuff where it definitely is dangerous.
The outer parts of the lamp connect to its ground I guess, so if through a malfunction there is a voltage from the chassis of the lamp to the ground, the resulting current could flow through the user.

Reasons why it's safe:

The power bank isn't connected to the ground, so why would current flow from the power bank through a user to the ground?

Notes:

It's a 150W power bank that has a bunch of USB and 12VDC ports and one 230V mains outlet. It doesn't have a ground connection at the outlet.
It's a 30W digitally controlled LED lamp which probably could be supplied from a low voltage direct current source more efficiently, but fact is it has a mains connection built in (no external power supply) and I don't want to (try to) convert it. It has a grounded plug (i.e. it doesn't fit the ungrounded outlet).


Related question: How likely is the lamp to work if I just hook up 12V to it's mains input? I think with some types of step-down+rectifier circuits this would work, right? Unless the lamp has all its LEDs in series and needs more than 12V.

The "Related question" should have been included in the body of the question, comments are not used as an "addendum" for any stuff you could and should have included in the question, especially before anyone has commented on your question. Additionally, your verbal descriptions provide little help in letting us know what you're dealing with because they could be any of the dozens or hundreds of different models. You should include pictures and model numbers, and any manuals, specifications and schematics you may have for the items you are asking about.

I think then it would be two questions and I should have opened a second question for that no, @EdinFifić ? But while I have put some thought into the actual question, I haven't done a reasonable amount of research on the related one and wouldn't ask it properly right now because I'm not sure if it's a stupid question.

Your question was loaded but it doesn't seem like a question, more of an explanation and as if you're asking for a confirmation. Your related question seems more like an actual question, but again you did not give us enough details (model numbers, pictures, datasheet, manuals, schematics) to be able to help you.

@EdinFifić The question is in the title where it's supposed to be. Showing an effort at answering your question is usually encouraged.

@Burglups I could only connect them by modifying the connectors/cable. Because the power bank outlet isn't grounded but the device plug has a ground connection so it doesn't fit ungrounded outlets. But the question is less about the specific device but more about the necessity of grounding a floating voltage device like a power bank.

What you /should/ do is use a double-insulated lamp without an earth wire. It used to be common to use un-earthed metal lamps but that's not common now because double-insulated or earthed lamps are safer.  And: you should not use a lamp with a disconnected earth wire because the existence of the wire implies an earth, and also invites misconnection: avoiding those is a user-level safety feature, not a physical safety feature.

just snap off the ground pin or use an adapter. it's safe since the AC is unbonded to earth.

@dandavis Well that's what I would have wanted to know, with some more reasoning. Pity they closed the question so you can't answer it... Thanks anyway.
